# Prefill github issue follow-up comments? (not initial comment)

Tags: github

Github allows you to populate the textbox when linking a user to create a new issue:

https://help.github.com/articles/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters/

Is there any similar feature when linking a user to comment on an existing issue?

(Not looking for an API solution due to the constraints of only being able to insert HTML links into the source application)